# Does designated initializer of sub-aggregate require curly braces?

Tags: c++, c++20, designated-initializer

In the following program, aggregate struct `B` has the field `a`, which is itself an aggregate. Can C++20 designated initializer be used to set its value without surrounding curly braces?

```
struct A { int i; };
struct B { A a; };

int main() { 
    [[maybe_unused]] B x{1}; //ok everywhere
    [[maybe_unused]] B y{.a = {1}}; //ok everywhere
    [[maybe_unused]] B z{.a = 1}; //ok in MSVC,Clang; error in GCC
}
```

MSVC and Clang compilers accept this code. But GCC issues a weird error:

```
error: 'A' has no non-static data member named 'a'
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/65j1sTcPG

Is it a bug in GCC, or such initialization is not permitted by the standard?

Comment: The error looks weird, but I hope it is correct to reject the third. It looks a lot like `A a = 1;` (which they'll all reject I'm sure).

Comment: Maybe it's parsing it like `B z {{.a = 1}};` ?

Comment: @NateEldredge That would make a lot of sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR; GCC is right, everyone else is wrong because they're pretending that designated initializer-lists act like equivalent non-designated initializer-lists all the time.

---

To understand what is happening here (and why compilers disagree), let's look at your first example:

```
B x{1};
```

Since we're using braces, the [rules of list initialization kick in](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.list#3). The list is not a designated initializer list, so 3.1 fails. 3.2 fails because `int` is not of type `B` or a type derived from `B`. 3.3 fails fails because `B` isn't an array of characters. Finally 3.4 is followed, which takes us to [aggregate initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr).

[[dcl.init.aggr]/3.2 tells us](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr) that the explicitly initialized elements of `B` consist of `B::a`.

Paragraph 4 tells us how the explicitly initialized elements are initialized. 4.1 doesn't apply, as `B` is not a `union`. But also... 4.2 doesn't apply because `B::a` cannot be copy-initialized from `1`.

That seems like it shouldn't work. Fortunately, [paragraphs 15 and 16 exist](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#15):

> Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. If the initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the elements of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more initializer-clauses than elements. If, however, the initializer-list for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the elements of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to initialize the next element of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is an element.
>
> All implicit type conversions ([conv]) are considered when initializing the element with an assignment-expression.
> If the assignment-expression can initialize an element, the element is initialized. Otherwise, if the element is itself a subaggregate, brace elision is assumed and the assignment-expression is considered for the initialization of the first element of the subaggregate.

That is, if the initializer cannot initialize `A` via copy-initialization, the rules of brace elision kick in. And `A` *can* be initialize from an initializer-list of `{1}`. Therefore, it is.

And this is where designated initializers have a problem. A `designated-initializer-list` is *not* an `initializer-list`. And therefore, the brace elision paragraphs *do not apply*.

And therefore, `B z{.a = 1};` must fail.

The reason the other compilers don't catch this is likely the following. They probably implement designated initializers by stripping out the designations and inserting any default member initializers/value initialization between non-consecutive elements, then applying normal aggregate initializer rules. But that's not quite the same thing, since designated initializer lists don't participate in brace elision.

Answer (score 1):

GCC is correct to **reject** this code: it attempts to copy-initialize `z.a` from `1` ([dcl.init.aggr]/4.2), which as the comments say doesn’t work.  The brace elision that GCC seems to be envisioning to produce the diagnostic is, however, invalid: that just doesn’t exist for designated-initializer-lists.